# Return nothing or all if overlaps fit somewhere PSQL

Tags: datetime, psql, interval

I have searched a bit and not come across anything comparable, so I'm asking this question here, hoping I haven't overlooked anything.

In my situation, we store deliveries on the database, which contain their time interval from start of delivery to the end. This looks roughly like this:

```sql
create table delivery_master (
    id uuid primary key,
    order_id uuid not null,
    start_time timestamp with time zone not null,
    end_time timestamp with time zone not null,
    delivery_id uuid null,
    quantity numeric(7,2) not null,
    vehicle_id uuid null,
    center_id uuid not null,
    unique(delivery_id)
);
```

As vehicles are assigned to certain centers, we first check which vehicles are assigned to what center and then use that list of `vehicle_id`s to proceed. This part is a relatively easy lookup.

Now, I get a new order, and I calculated how many deliveries they have and their start and end time. I now want to query the DB, to see which of the vehicles that are assigned, have *open spaces* to fit these deliveries in.

This has some additional problems: A vehicle can be assigned to multiple delivery centers (i.e. imagine that both are relatively close so they could in theory on their way pickup something from the second center).

My current query looks like this:

```sql
select pdm.*
from delivery_master dm,
unnest(
    '{2023-05-04T08:00:00Z, 2023-05-04T09:07:00Z}'::timestamptz[],'{2023-05-04T10:00:00Z, 2023-05-04T12:00:00Z}'::timestamptz[]
    ) periods(stime, etime)
where dm.vehicle_id in ('0a2c7f64-f465-4501-8a98-6ebb255dcf98', '87bc94dc-4da8-4f47-9b47-a79257997ce0')
    and not (dm.start_time,dm.end_time) OVERLAPS (periods.stime, periods.etime)
    and date(dm.start_time) = '2023-05-04';
```

Now, in my case I have 2 vehicles that are assigned to the center that should deliver the order. With that list, I now also supply a list of all `start_time` and `end_time` of the predictions I just made. My goal is to check, for all vehicles, if any have timeslots not overlapping said predictions. In that case, I want it to return all the rows of said vehicles; so that I can do manual assignment on the backend.

My problem now is, that the returned rows *only* contain the rows *that don't overlap*. In my case I would want, that if any of the "viable" rows doesn't overlap, to return all rows.

EDIT: After a request, this would be an example dataset for it. The current query would only return a part of this dataset, but the goal would be for it to return all of them.

```sql
insert into delivery_master values
('cb96ca55-8d00-43da-a015-fd1f3a8283d2','f00fb9dc-b212-4be3-a936-df1f3420b215','2023-05-04 07:33:00+00','2023-05-04 09:06:00+00','d5d6a4ce-d552-444b-b983-b299b5a321da',8.00,'0a2c7f64-f465-4501-8a98-6ebb255dcf98','2dfa4013-a312-4247-9f29-3e21631ace6b'),
('cb96ca55-8d00-43da-a015-fd1f3a8283d2','f00fb9dc-b212-4be3-a936-df1f3420b215','2023-05-04 07:33:00+00','2023-05-04 09:06:00+00','d5d6a4ce-d552-444b-b983-b299b5a321da',8.00,'0a2c7f64-f465-4501-8a98-6ebb255dcf98','2dfa4013-a312-4247-9f29-3e21631ace6b'),
('8e3f8cd6-7a11-4759-887e-e6970d3381b6','f00fb9dc-b212-4be3-a936-df1f3420b215','2023-05-04 06:21:00+00','2023-05-04 07:52:00+00','3cfc2389-1247-47cf-86bb-d1741f673cda',8.00,'87bc94dc-4da8-4f47-9b47-a79257997ce0','2dfa4013-a312-4247-9f29-3e21631ace6b'),
('8e3f8cd6-7a11-4759-887e-e6970d3381b6','f00fb9dc-b212-4be3-a936-df1f3420b215','2023-05-04 06:21:00+00','2023-05-04 07:52:00+00','3cfc2389-1247-47cf-86bb-d1741f673cda',8.00,'87bc94dc-4da8-4f47-9b47-a79257997ce0','2dfa4013-a312-4247-9f29-3e21631ace6b'),
('5273b249-58ee-4636-af7a-dadd3575bd86','f00fb9dc-b212-4be3-a936-df1f3420b215','2023-05-04 08:39:00+00','2023-05-04 10:12:00+00','4792cc4d-875e-421c-8f5c-b5d46f17c604',2.50,'0a2c7f64-f465-4501-8a98-6ebb255dcf98','2dfa4013-a312-4247-9f29-3e21631ace6b'),
('5273b249-58ee-4636-af7a-dadd3575bd86','f00fb9dc-b212-4be3-a936-df1f3420b215','2023-05-04 08:39:00+00','2023-05-04 10:12:00+00','4792cc4d-875e-421c-8f5c-b5d46f17c604',2.50,'0a2c7f64-f465-4501-8a98-6ebb255dcf98','2dfa4013-a312-4247-9f29-3e21631ace6b'),
('80322214-66c9-46dd-88f5-d949ffa58c89','230c9ea8-60fe-4472-894a-7fe866a0383c','2023-05-04 07:25:00+00','2023-05-04 09:38:00+00','cc76622d-f9ed-4f25-b5cb-bf8ad01c29f6',7.50,'87bc94dc-4da8-4f47-9b47-a79257997ce0','2dfa4013-a312-4247-9f29-3e21631ace6b'),
('80322214-66c9-46dd-88f5-d949ffa58c89','230c9ea8-60fe-4472-894a-7fe866a0383c','2023-05-04 07:25:00+00','2023-05-04 09:38:00+00','cc76622d-f9ed-4f25-b5cb-bf8ad01c29f6',7.50,'87bc94dc-4da8-4f47-9b47-a79257997ce0','2dfa4013-a312-4247-9f29-3e21631ace6b'),
('db7e0c5a-9b54-4133-939e-5bed5487943e','6b0bac44-ded2-41d8-b581-7c798f52a22f','2023-05-04 10:25:00+00','2023-05-04 11:32:00+00','a1e66278-cc3d-4f9b-bd80-913628d5a7bd',2.00,'87bc94dc-4da8-4f47-9b47-a79257997ce0','2dfa4013-a312-4247-9f29-3e21631ace6b'),
('db7e0c5a-9b54-4133-939e-5bed5487943e','6b0bac44-ded2-41d8-b581-7c798f52a22f','2023-05-04 10:25:00+00','2023-05-04 11:32:00+00','a1e66278-cc3d-4f9b-bd80-913628d5a7bd',2.00,'87bc94dc-4da8-4f47-9b47-a79257997ce0','2dfa4013-a312-4247-9f29-3e21631ace6b'),
('defa7fff-77b5-4291-99d3-2ac39abb3b69','48e2a591-7b34-4291-91f0-955a583f6e97','2023-05-04 16:30:33+00','2023-05-04 19:30:33+00',null,7.00,'0a2c7f64-f465-4501-8a98-6ebb255dcf98','9f14bbb3-279b-4e7a-8082-8bb89cfa0b3d'),
('defa7fff-77b5-4291-99d3-2ac39abb3b69','48e2a591-7b34-4291-91f0-955a583f6e97','2023-05-04 16:30:33+00','2023-05-04 19:30:33+00',null,7.00,'0a2c7f64-f465-4501-8a98-6ebb255dcf98','9f14bbb3-279b-4e7a-8082-8bb89cfa0b3d');
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely

Comment: @Charlieface I've added a small insert for it

Comment: And expected results

Comment: The insert is the complete (should be) result set of the query.

Comment: So what's the sample data then?

Comment: The sample data is in the insert, which is the absolute minimum require to test it. The query as is should return the exact same amount (to make evaluation easy), but doesn't. Are you expecting more sample data?

Comment: No, I'm just confused, is the `INSERT` the sample input or the expected result? We need both

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, will clarify in the question. But basically, you insert that data, and the query _should_ return all rows, but only returns those that don't overlap.

Comment: You have duplicate rows in your sample, but after removing them I get all six rows back in the query https://dbfiddle.uk/yUEWluNX It seems you have some way of defining "all rows", is that per `vehicle_id` or something else?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! I'm puzzled - `quantity numeric(7,2) not null,` - why is this `NUMERIC`? Normally vehicles aren't delivered in fractions?